# How to find CDF and PDF of $Y = 4X(1-X)$, given $X\in[0,1]$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and $Y = 4X(1− X)$. Find the CDF and PDF of $Y$.

Comment: you must solve x=f(y) equation and then derive pdf of Y

Comment: what is your derivations ?

Comment: Sorry that's all information the question provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=4x(1-x)$ is a non-negative function over the interval $[0,1]$, symmetric with respect to $x=\frac{1}{2}$, where $g(x)$ attains its maximum, $1$. By computing the inverse function of $g:\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\to[0,1]$:

$$\forall t\in[0,1],\qquad \mathbb{P}[Y\leq t]=1-\sqrt{1-t} \tag{1}$$
and by differentiation we have that the PDF of $Y$ is supported on $[0,1]$ and given by:
$$ f_Y(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-t}}.\tag{2} $$

Comment: how you get the P(Y<t) ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear about how do you get $P[Y \leq t] = 1 - \sqrt{1-t}$. Is there a formula for it or some other works you've done?

Comment: @appsung: what is the inverse function of $g(x)$?

Comment: that is exactly what i said in comments. it would be better to mention that